# Select all Radio Buttons from different groups with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to know if there is a clever way to select all radio buttons from diferent groups at once.

It's an old site, so i cant use jquery.

This is what I got so far.

I put the code on codepen, its look pretty simple to me, but  I think maybe there are some easiest way to achieve the same results.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/joexadrez/pen/DzctL)

HTML:

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="0">No<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="0">No<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group3" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group3" value="0">No
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="group4" value="1" onclick="selectAll(form1)">All Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group4" value="0" onClick="selectAll(form1)" >All No
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAll(form1) {

      var check = document.getElementsByName("group4"),
            radios = document.form1.elements;

        if (check[0].checked) {

            for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {

                if( radios[i].type == "radio" ) {

                    if (radios[i].value == 1 ) {

                        radios[i].checked = true;
                    }

                }

            }

        } else {

            for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {

                if( radios[i].type == "radio" ) {

                    if (radios[i].value == 0 ) {

                        radios[i].checked = true;

                    }

                }

            }

        };
      return null;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the onclick to `selectAll(this)` you can get away with this:

```
function selectAll( check ) {
    var radio, i=0;
    while( radio=check.form.elements[i++] )
        if( radio.type == "radio" && radio.value == check.value )
            radio.checked = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.You need to pass current page as an parameter onclick="selectAll(this).like this

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="0">No<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="0">No<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group3" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group3" value="0">No
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="group4" value="1" onclick="selectAll(this)">All Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="group4" value="0" onClick="selectAll(this)" >All No
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectAll( check ) {
    var radio, i=0;
    while( radio=check.form.elements[i++] )
        if( radio.type == "radio" && radio.value == check.value )
            radio.checked = true;
};
</script>
```